# why are Gridview, datagrid and similar controls transparent in run time in VB.NET VS2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i am new to VB.NET , previously i have worked with vb 6.0 few years back, wanted to develop an application in vb.net vs-2013 but i see that these controls are transparent and many other controls behave the same way.

[image]

Comment: Image link is private....

Comment: sorry , forgot to change settings, 
link updated